# Calling a rest service only once in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-directive

We have menu's that can be displayed based on the role. I made the directive for this feature. But the problem is everytime I call the directive its calling rest service. I want to be able to call it only once and save the features that can be accessed for the current role and decide either hide it or show. Below is currently what I have:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('authService', function(){

var user = {};
user.role = 'guest';
return{
getFeature: function(){
  //rest service call
  return featureList;
 },

  }
});

app.directive('restrict', function(authService){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    prioriry: 100000,
    scope: false,
    compile:  function(element, attr, linker){
        var accessDenied = true;
        var featureList = authService.getFeature();
        featureList.then(function(result){
          featureList = result;

        var attributes = attr.access.split(" ");
        for(var i in featureList){
            if(featureList[i] == attributes[0]){
                accessDenied = false;
            }
        }


        if(accessDenied){
            element.children().remove();
            element.remove();           
        }
       });
    }
  }
 });
```

Is there anyway I can call rest service only once not with every directive call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to cache the result from the service call, like so

```
app.service('authService', function($q) {

    var user = {};
    var cache;

    user.role = 'guest';
    return {
        getFeature: function() {
            if (cache) {
                return $q.when(cache);
            } else {
                //rest service call
                return featureList.then(function(val) {
                    cache = val;
                    return val;
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You'll only make the call once (as long as the result is truthy), after that you'll just be returning the cache.

Might want to consider how to invalidate the cache at some point, depending on the apps needs.

---

**Edit**

As per comments, previous solution would allow multiple calls while waiting for the promise to resolve.

This approach will always return one singular promise, which itself does the single rest call.

```
app.service('authService', function($http) {

    var user = {};
    var prom;

    user.role = 'guest';
    return {
        getFeature: function() {
            if (!prom) {
                prom = $http.get(/rest/).then(function(result) {
                    return result.data;
                });
            }
            return prom;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Wierd, it's always going into else loop.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point on the 'cache = val' line, to see if it ever executes?  The featureList may be throwing an error which never gets caught.

Comment: Yeah, it is executing, the problem is when I put a console statement for cache before if loop, it's calling n times  saying 'undefined' and then calling rest service in else loop n times(depending on directive calls).

Comment: Ah, right.  If all of the directives are compiling at the same time then the promise will not have resolved yet, so cache will be empty.  I'll edit it

Comment: It worked with couple of changes.This is what I did: if(!prom){
         prom = $http.get(/rest/).then(function(result) {
           
             return result.data;
            });
         } 
         
          return prom; May be you can edit your answer.

Comment: Sure, check out the edit and see if that's what you're looking for @nullPointer2